# SimpleDotCom java error

Tags: java

Soonly ill freak out. I have done everything i can!
The problem: when I try to run my program in the command line i get this error:

> error: cannot find symbol
>         SimpleDotCom dot = new SimpleDotCom();
>         ^                      ^
>   symbol: class SimpleDotCom
>   location: class SimpleDotComTestDrive

Here is the code:

```
public class SimpleDotComTestDrive {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        SimpleDotCom dot = new SimpleDotCom();

        int[] locations = {2, 3 ,4};

        dot.setLocationCells(locations);

        String userGuess = "2";

        String result = dot.checkYourself(userGuess);

    }

public class SimpleDotCom {

    int[] locationCells;
    int numOfHits = 0;

    public void setLocationCells(int[] locs) {
        locationCells = locs;   
    }

    public String checkYourself(String stringGuess) {

        int guess = Integer.parseInt(stringGuess);
        String result = "miss";
        for (int cell : locationCells) {

            if (guess == cell) {

                result = "hit";
                numOfHits++;
                break;

            }
        }   
        if (numOfHits == locationCells.length) {

            result = "kill";

        }

        System.out.println(result);
        return result;



   }

}
```

Comment: Try defining `SimpleDotCom` as a `static` class. You try to use it from a static context, but at the moment, it is not static. In general, it is preferred to put each class in a new file.

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
SimpleDotCom dot = new SimpleDotCom();
```

fails as you can't instantiate an inner class without an enclosing instance. Instead you could write

```
SimpleDotCom dot = (new SimpleDotComTestDrive()).new SimpleDotCom();
```

which will provide an enclosing instance inline. Alternatively, just make the class `SimpleDotCom` static, which means it won't have an enclosing instance.

Answer (score 0):

If SimpleDotCom is an inner class, it needs to be "assigned" to an instance of the outer class

```
SimpleDotComTestDrive outer = new SimpleDotComTestDrive();
outer.SimpleDotCom dot = outer.new SimpleDotCom();
```

Still this doesn´t work in a static enviroment as is `main`

The other option is make the inner class `static` and access it through  `SimpleDotComTestDrive.SimpleDotCom`

Comment: I don't think that's correct. As mentioned in my comment and in @Reimeus' answer, the class must be static so it can be accessed in the static `main` method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep these two classes in different class files. This code is working properly in both, eclipse as well as the command-line compiler.

**This is what you have to do. 1) Create a class called SimpleDotComTestDrive and put this part of your code in it**

```
public class SimpleDotComTestDrive {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        SimpleDotCom dot = new SimpleDotCom();

        int[] locations = {2, 3 ,4};

        dot.setLocationCells(locations);

        String userGuess = "2";

        String result = dot.checkYourself(userGuess);

    }
}
```

**And then create another class called SimpleDotCom and paste this code**

```
public class SimpleDotCom {

    int[] locationCells;
    int numOfHits = 0;

void setLocationCells(int[] locs) {
        locationCells = locs;   
    }

    String checkYourself(String stringGuess) {

        int guess = Integer.parseInt(stringGuess);
        String result = "miss";
        for (int cell : locationCells) {

            if (guess == cell) {

                result = "hit";
                numOfHits++;
                break;

            }
        }   
        if (numOfHits == locationCells.length) {

            result = "kill";

        }

        System.out.println(result);
        return result;



   }

}
```